# Output Truncation in Google colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

[1]In google colab, While viewing the variable, it always truncates after a certain limit  in the output screen

Colab, I tried to print the string as whole even characters but at the end it prints as (...)

```
import pandas as pd 
d = {'Title': ["Hello, hope you are doing good, every one is fine in your place"]}
m = pd.DataFrame(d)
m['Title']
```

output:

> 0    Hello, hope you are doing good, every one is f...

I need to view the full output as the whole string.

[Output is truncated]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZ7pJ.jpg

Comment: Show your [mcve].

Comment: @jdv Thanks for your comment. Please look at the updated question.

Comment: This looks like a display artefact in the UI. There are probably options to control this. Make sure you do a little research using "jupyter" or "pandas" as search terms; there are some hints there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're observing a 'feature' of Pandas wherein it truncates long strings when formatting DataFrame objects.

To configure the truncation limit, use:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth',1000)
```

(Of course, you can adjust the value `1000` to whatever you prefer.)

Afterward, your example will produce the expected output like so:

[image]